# I want to send an value via ajax when the input is focused with keypress

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, chat

I'm currently trying to write a chat, but this piece of my code doesn't work the way I want.

```
$("#chat").focus(function() {
            $(document).keypress(function(e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    $.post("send.php",
                            {
                                chat: $("#chat").val()
                            }

                            );

                }
            });
        });
```

The "send.php" works. The page reloads, which it should not do and my value is deleted.

Hope for your help.
Thank you in anticipation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `return false;`

```
$("#chat").focus(function() {
   $(document).keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
         $.post("send.php",{ chat: $("#chat").val() });
          return false;
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

throw in a `e.preventDefault();` right before your if statement This will stop the default behavior, which is a page refresh in this case.